# PHP Help, not recognizing the different users

Tags: php

I have little knowledge with PHP and I was assigned to try to fix some of the things that don't work in a website. The website basically deals with two different users, a trader who can post articles and a blogger who can post blogs. When a user registers to become a trader and tries to submit an article,the page just redirects to `base_url.user/blogger/` instead of `base_url.user/trader/`. I think this is because it isn't recognizing the user as a trader. Can you please look at the codes?  If you have any ideas as to why it wouldn't work I'm open to ideas

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed 
     *
     * 
     * File Controller; location: application/controllers/admin.php
     * Author : Pradeep
     * Date  :  Sunday Feb 5th, 2012
**/
class Register extends CI_Controller {


    private $user;
    private $logData;


    function _Register()
    {
        parent::controller();
        $this->config->load('constants.php');


    }
    public function blogger()
    {
        //-------------------------SENDING ERROR MESSAGE FOR LOGIN-------------------
        $data['captchaError'] = '';
        $data['captcha'] = $this->getCaptcha();
        $data['pageTitle']='Registration | Blogger';
        $this->load->view('register-blogger',$data);
    }
    public function trader()
    {
        $data['captchaError'] = '';
        $data['captcha'] = $this->getCaptcha();
        $data['pageTitle']='Registration | Trader';
        $this->load->view('register-trader',$data);
    }
    public function activate()
    {

        $data['pageTitle']='Registration | Succesfully registered';
        $this->load->view('register-success',$data);
    }


    public function process()
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $userid = uniqid();
        $captchaError = '';
        if($this->input->post('Submit'))
        {
//---------------------------------FORM VALIDATION STARTS HERE---------------------------------
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Full name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[tbl_user.email]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[cpassword]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Password confirmation', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mycheck[]', 'Buyer or Supplier','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('material[]', 'materials','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Company name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cname', 'Contact name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cemail', 'Contact email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nation', 'Country', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fax');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('website');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('zip');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'Tell something about urself', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('captchaText', 'captcha text', 'required');
//-----------------------------------FORM VALIDATION ENDS HERE--------------------------------------


//------------------------------------CAPTCHA CHECK------------------------------------------
            if($this->input->post('captchaText'))
            {
                $expiration = time()-7200; // Two hour limit
                $this->db->query("DELETE FROM captcha WHERE captcha_time < ".$expiration);

            // Then see if a captcha exists:
                $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM captcha WHERE word = ? AND ip_address = ? AND captcha_time > ?";
                $binds = array($_POST['captchaText'], $this->input->ip_address(), $expiration);
                $query = $this->db->query($sql, $binds);
                $row = $query->row();

                if ($row->count == 0)
                {
                $captchaError =  "You must submit the word that appears in the image";
                }
            }
//--------------------------------------CAPTCHA CHECK ENDS HERE----------------------------

//----------------------------------FORM VALIDATION RETURN ERRORS---------------------------
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE || $captchaError!='')
            {
            $data['captcha'] = $this->getCaptcha();
            $data['captchaError'] = $captchaError;
            $data['pageTitle']='Registration | Error';
            $this->load->view('register-trader',$data);
            }
//-----------------------------------------------END---------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE-----------------------
            else
            {
            if($this->input->post('material'))
                {
                $material = '';
                foreach($this->input->post('material') as $value)
                {
                $material.= $value.',';
                }
            $material = rtrim($material,',');
            }
            $mycheck = $this->input->post('mycheck');
            $mycheckOne = '';
            $mycheckTwo = '';
            if(!empty($mycheck[0])){$mycheckOne = $mycheck[0];}
            if(!empty($mycheck[1])){$mycheckTwo = $mycheck[1];}
            $config['file_name'] = uniqid(); 
            $config['upload_path'] = UP_PATH;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1000';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile1'))
            {               
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $data = array(
                  'supplier'=>$mycheckOne,
                  'buyer'=>$mycheckTwo,
                  'title'=>$this->input->post('company'),
                  'cname'=>$this->input->post('cname'),
                  'material'=>$material,
                  'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                  'phone'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
                  'fax'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                  'mobile'=>$this->input->post('mobile'),
                  'web'=>$this->input->post('website'),
                  'country'=>$this->input->post('nation'),
                  'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),
                  'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
                  'zip'=>$this->input->post('zip'),
                  'content'=>$this->input->post('content'),
                  'date'=>$date,
                  'userid'=>$userid,
                  'status'=>0
                );

            }   
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
                $filepath = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = UP_PATH.$filepath;
                $config['new_image'] = UP_PATH.'thumbs/';
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['thumb_marker'] = '';
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 75;
                $config['height'] = 50;
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();

                $data = array(
                  'supplier'=>$mycheckOne,
                  'buyer'=>$mycheckTwo,
                  'title'=>$this->input->post('company'),
                  'cname'=>$this->input->post('cname'),
                  'material'=>$material,
                  'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                  'phone'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
                  'fax'=>$this->input->post('fax'),
                  'mobile'=>$this->input->post('mobile'),
                  'web'=>$this->input->post('website'),
                  'country'=>$this->input->post('nation'),
                  'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),
                  'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
                  'zip'=>$this->input->post('zip'),
                  'content'=>$this->input->post('content'),
                  'image'=>$filepath,
                  'date'=>$date,
                  'userid'=>$userid,
                  'status'=>0
                  );

            }   
            $this->db->insert(TBL_CLA,$data);
            $log_type = 'trader';
            $password = do_hash($this->input->post('password'));
            $dataOne = array(
                  'password'=>$this->security->xss_clean($password),
                  'fname'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('fname')),
                  'email'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('email')),
                  'log_type'=>$log_type,
                  'userid'=>$userid,
                  'status'=>0,
                  'date'=>$date,
                  'active'=>1
                  );
            $this->db->insert(TBL_USE,$dataOne);

            $this->session->set_userdata('fname', $this->input->post('fname'));
            redirect(base_url().'register/activate');
            }
            }
            if($this->input->post('Login'))
            {
//---------------------------------FORM VALIDATION STARTS HERE---------------------------------
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Full name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[tbl_user.email]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[cpassword]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Password confirmation', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('captchaText', 'captcha text', 'required');
//-----------------------------------FORM VALIDATION ENDS HERE--------------------------------------


//------------------------------------CAPTCHA CHECK------------------------------------------
            if($this->input->post('captchaText'))
            {
                $expiration = time()-7200; // Two hour limit
                $this->db->query("DELETE FROM captcha WHERE captcha_time < ".$expiration);

            // Then see if a captcha exists:
                $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM captcha WHERE word = ? AND ip_address = ? AND captcha_time > ?";
                $binds = array($_POST['captchaText'], $this->input->ip_address(), $expiration);
                $query = $this->db->query($sql, $binds);
                $row = $query->row();

                if ($row->count == 0)
                {
                $captchaError =  "You must submit the word that appears in the image";
                }
            }
//--------------------------------------CAPTCHA CHECK ENDS HERE----------------------------

//----------------------------------FORM VALIDATION RETURN ERRORS---------------------------
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE || $captchaError!='')
            {
            $data['captcha'] = $this->getCaptcha();
            $data['captchaError'] = $captchaError;
            $data['pageTitle']='Registration | Error';
            $this->load->view('register-blogger',$data);
            }
//-----------------------------------------------END---------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE-----------------------
            else
            {
            $date = date('Y-m-d');
            $log_type = 'blogger';
            $password = do_hash($this->input->post('password'));
            $dataOne = array(
                  'password'=>$this->security->xss_clean($password),
                  'fname'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('fname')),
                  'email'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('email')),
                  'log_type'=>$log_type,
                  'userid'=>$userid,
                  'status'=>0,
                  'date'=>$date,
                  'active'=>0
                  );
            $this->db->insert(TBL_USE,$dataOne);
            $data['link'] = 'http://www.arabrecycling.org/activate/created/'.$userid;
            $data['name'] = $this->input->post('fname');
            $message = $this->load->view('includes/activate',$data, TRUE);
            $subject = 'Account Activation';
            $fromTest = 'The Arab Recycling Initiative';
            $this->userRegEmail('info@arabrecycling.org',$this->input->post('email'),$message,$subject,$fromTest);
            $this->session->set_userdata('fname', $this->input->post('fname'));
            redirect(base_url().'register/activate');
            }
            }


    }
//-------------------------------------------------------CAPTCHA CREATION STARTS HERE------------------------
    public function getCaptcha(){

            $this->load->library('common');
            $this->common = new common();

            $this->load->helper('captcha');
            $vals = array(
            'word' => $this->common->GetRandomCaptchaText(8),
            'img_path' => './captcha/',
            'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
            'font_path' => base_url().'system/fonts/Candice.ttf',
            'img_width' => '150',
            'img_height' => 30,
            'expiration' => 7200
            );

            $cap = create_captcha($vals);

            $data = array(
            'captcha_time' => $cap['time'],
            'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
            'word' => $cap['word']
            );

            $query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $data);
            $this->db->query($query);

            return $cap['image'];
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------CAPTCHA CREATION ENDS HERE------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------CONFIGURING EMAIL------------------------------------------------
        public function userRegEmail($from,$to,$message,$subject,$fromTest){
             $email_config['protocol'] = 'mail';
             $email_config['mailtype'] = 'html';
             $this->email->initialize($email_config);

             $this->email->from($from, $fromTest);
             $this->email->to($to);         
             $this->email->subject($subject);
             $this->email->message($message); 
             $this->email->send();
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------EMAIL CONFIGURATION ENDS HERE------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The registration code shouldn't matter that much. I don't see any redirects to trader here. Can you put only the session management code - when user logs in you should be able to get his registration type and redirect him accordingly

Comment: this is the start of the form that the user fills out to become a trader. I'm wondering, shouldn't there be a redirect to trader in the register process?

 <form action="<?=base_url()?>register/process" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><

Answer (score 0):

You should identify if a user is a trader or a blogger, and then set appropriate session variables accordingly. A simple if statement to check which is logged in depending on which session variable is set should do the trick? If i'm understanding your question correctly.

What I would suggest (it will probably be easier) is

**1. add an attribute to your user table in your database that is Account_Type enum('trader','blogger') not null**.

**2. Add radio buttons to your form when they sign up to choose if they are a trader or blogger
and obviously have this data sent back to your database**

**3. When they Login (i'm assuming all users have a unique username) do something like**

*-Set Session variables to 0*

```
  $_SESSION['trader'] = 0;
  $_SESSION['blogger'] = 0;
```

*-find username in database and for that username check if trader or blogger.*

```
//A Query to find the Account_type that goes with the input account 
$accquery = "SELECT Account_type FROM Account WHERE Account_Name =$_POST['account']";

//Running the query
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$accquery);


//Using an array to fetch the type and put it into a variables place
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($connect,$result))
{
$acctype = $row['Account_Type']; 
}



else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

*And then do something like*

```
if($acctype == "trader") {
  $_SESSION['trader'] = 1;
elseif($acctype == "Blogger") {
  $_SESSION['blogger'] =1;
else {
  //error message
}
```

and then when you need to check which they are you can do something like

```
 if((isset($_SESSION['trader'])) && ($_SESSION['trader'] == "1")){
   //specific code for trader
   }
```

and you can apply the same for blogger.

I would also advise you look into sanitizing your inputs, it's simple but very important.

Also note, do a thorough search through stackoverflow for answers to your questions because more than likely you will find something.

-Hope this helps, note its only rough so you will have to work around it but you should have some grasp of PHP anyways so that should do.

Comment: yes, I was thinking the same thing. Umm I'm still new to PHP where would you suggest I try to write the IF statement

Comment: @user3506267 I've given this an edit, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Use SESSIONS:

On top of your page set:

```
<?php 
  //Check if session has not been started.
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
  {
    session_start();
  }
?>
```

In the code when defining a trader or blogger:

```
$_SESSION['USER'] = "trader";
```

or

```
$_SESSION['USER'] = "blogger";
```

Then you can execute the code you want:

```
//If it has not been set, do trader by default.
if (!ISSET($_SESSION['USER'])
{
    $_SESSION['USER'] = "trader";
}

if ($_SESSION['USER'] == "blogger")
{
   //Execute code for blogger
}
else if($_SESSION['USER'] == "trader")
{
   //Execute code for trader
}
```

Sessions are stored in your browser as long as your "Page/Session" is open. Those "Variables" are user specific.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I mentioned that I have very little knowledge in PHP could you please assist me